# Getting values from multiple radio buttons MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in my view (See picture below) where I need to collect the values from a radio button group. So then I push the next button I have a list with the values for each table row. This is my code in the view.

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.convertedSubjectsList)
    {
      <tr>
         <td>
           <br />
           <br />
           @item.Part
           <br />
           <br />
        </td>
        <td>
           @item.Name
        </td>
        <td>
         <form>
            <input type="radio" name="used" value="yes" /> 
             @Resources.Resources.SubjectRadioYes<br />
            <input type="radio" name="used" value="no" /> 
             @Resources.Resources.SubjectRadioNo
          </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
    }
```

Is this posible?

[image: See picture]

Comment: Wait your question is "Is this possible" and you then provide a print screen of what it looks like. something doesn't quite add up...

Comment: The picture is to show how the view is right now, to better context. If it's so big problem for you i can just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
<form method=post action="@Url.Action("Save")">
<table>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.convertedSubjectsList)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
      <br /><br />
      @item.Part
      <br /><br />
    </td>
    <td>
      @item.Name
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="@item.Part" value="yes" />
      Yes<br />
      <input type="radio" name="@item.Part" value="no" />
      No
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(FormCollection form)
{
    foreach (var item in form.AllKeys)
    {
        string value = form[item];
        // save data 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Different things

All your radiobuttons should be in the same form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    //yourcode
}
```

Then I would put the "convertedSubjectList" as the model (or a part of a ViewModel used as model).

let's say the model is of type `IEnumerable<ConvertedSubject>`;

then to loop and retrieve elements

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Part)</td>
         <td>@Html.Displayfor(m => Model[i].Name)</td>
         <td>@Html.RadioButtonYesNoFor(m => Model[i].xxx)</td>//name of the property used for radio value
         //you could use a CheckBoxFor, if you have only "yes/no", but as you want
     </tr>
}
```

a little HtmlHelper

```
public static IHtmlString RadioButtonYesNoFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0} {1}", html.RadioButtonFor(expression, true).ToHtmlString(), "Yes"));
            stringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0} {1}", html.RadioButtonFor(expression, false).ToHtmlString(), "No"));
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(stringBuilder.ToString());
        }
```

Then you should be able to get back your datas as an IList in your posted action.